# Eclipse error: a Child component failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat7

I installed Apache tomcat 7 in my eclipse. I created a server and started it which is working fine. When I am trying to run any project, even a simple JSP hello world file, then the following error occurs.

Example: I created a web dynamic project with just a "index.jsp", but this problem is occurring and I don't know how solve it.

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Example]]

Comment: is there a solution you have found for this?

Answer (score 0):

test:

1. delete tomcat from your server list.
2. delete the folder .metadata from your workbench.
3. restart eclipse and open ur workbench.
4. add tomcat at ur server list.
5. import ur project.

finally **maven** -> **upDate**.